# Clicking on javascript anchor with htmlunit does not seem to work

Tags: java, javascript, anchor, htmlunit

I am using htmlunit to automatically go through a website.
Here is the problem:

I want to click on an anchor in order to display a new page of a given table.

Here is the anchor:

```
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('GridView1','Page$7')">7</a>
```

Here is my code:

```
final HtmlAnchor a = page2.getAnchorByText("7");
HtmlPage page3 = a.click();
System.out.println(page2.getWebResponse().getContentAsString())
System.out.println(page3.getWebResponse().getContentAsString());
```

I do not have any error message. When I compare my print out, they are identical, and yet they shouldn't be, as I just clicked on an anchor. First print out should display a certain page of the table, a the second print out another one.

The stackoverflow post [struggling to click on link within htmlunit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244005/struggling-to-click-on-link-within-htmlunit) renders a very similar problem, however his solution (setting the browser version to the webclient) does not appear to work in my case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you need to wait for the javascript to excute and load first. I suggest to use the following command:

```
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(1000);
```

or even:

```
JavaScriptJobManager manager = page.getEnclosingWindow().getJobManager();
while (manager.getJobCount() > 0) {
    Thread.sleep(100);
}
```

and yet another option:

```
webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
webClient.setAjaxController(new AjaxController(){
    @Override
    public boolean processSynchron(HtmlPage page, WebRequest request, boolean async)
    {
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: can u show by taking the code from the question as an example?
`final HtmlAnchor a = page2.getAnchorByText("7");
HtmlPage page3 = a.click();
System.out.println(page2.getWebResponse().getContentAsString())
System.out.println(page3.getWebResponse().getContentAsString());`

Answer (score 0):

final HtmlAnchor a = page2.getAnchorByText("7");
HtmlPage page3 = a.click();

// add this client.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(10000); here
client.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(10000);

System.out.println(page2.getWebResponse().getContentAsString())
System.out.println(page3.getWebResponse().getContentAsString());

Comment: Could you please explain why this works? Also, note that you can use three backticks to enter 'code mode', which enables syntax highlighting.